# Laravel 5.1 queryScope or Accessor on Image with path

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am currently stuck on something.  Right now I have an Ad controller that hasMany images.

```
class Ad extends Model
{
   public function images()
   {
       return $this->hasMany('Core\Entities\Ad\AdImages', 'ad_id', 'id')->orderBy('img_is_default', 'desc');
   }
}
```

The images table has a column for image_name (e.g my.jpg and another column for image path img_path (e.g '`custom/folder/images/date`')

The problem or hassle here is when I loop out images in a view I have to also add in `$result->image_path ./.$result->image_name`.

Does anyone know how I can just get image path and image name combined into one from like a queryScope?

Basically I would just want to do like `$result->primaryImage()`  which would then output `custom/folder/images/date/myimage.jpg`

^ already formatted.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an accessor

```
class AdImage ....
{
    public function getFullPathAttribute()
    {
        return $this->attributes['image_path'] .'/'. $this->attributes['image_name'];
    }
}

$img->full_path; // the combined value from above
```

[Laravel 5.2 Docs - Eloquent - Accessors and Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators)

Comment: And you can even make this shorter by doing: `return $this->image_path .'/'. $this->image_name;`